# GPUImageMovieWriter and avfiletypempeg4 filetype

Tags: ios, avfoundation, gpuimage

First of all I would like congratulate Brad for the amazing work on GPUImage.

I'm trying to apply a rotation to a given video file and obtain an mpeg4 (AVFileTypeMPEG4) file as output.

When doing this I obtain the following message :

* -[AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:] Input buffer must be in an uncompressed format when outputSettings is not nil

This problem occurs when using the following init method of GPUImageMovieWriter with filetype set to AVFileTypeMPEG4 :

```
- (id)initWithMovieURL:(NSURL *)newMovieURL size:(CGSize)newSize fileType:(NSString *)newFileType outputSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)outputSettings;
```

However it works for the another init method which in fact generate quicktime movie (AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie is set by default).

```
- (id)initWithMovieURL:(NSURL *)newMovieURL size:(CGSize)newSize;
```

Please can anybody say me if GPUImageWriter is capable from now to output mpeg4 movie file.

After many investigation and tries you can see below one of the several code I made.

```
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:inputUrl];
movieFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
[movieFilter setInputRotation:videoRotationMode atIndex:0];
[movieFile addTarget:movieFilter];
unlink([[outputUrl path] UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie

NSMutableDictionary *videoSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];;
[videoSettings setObject:AVVideoCodecH264 forKey:AVVideoCodecKey];
[videoSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:width] forKey:AVVideoWidthKey];
[videoSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:height] forKey:AVVideoHeightKey];



AudioChannelLayout channelLayout;
memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;

NSDictionary *audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 2 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 16000.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [ NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout length: sizeof( AudioChannelLayout ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 32000 ], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                nil];



// Will create quicktime file
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:outputUrl size:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0) fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 outputSettings:videoSettings];


[movieFilter addTarget:movieWriter];
// Configure this for video from the movie file, where we want to preserve all video frames and audio samples
movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = NO; // default YES
[movieWriter setHasAudioTrack:TRUE audioSettings:audioSettings];
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

[movieWriter setDelegate:self];
[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];
```

Thanks in advance

PS : I'm using iOS6

Comment: The movie files recorded using AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie are indeed MPEG4-compliant movies. They contain H.264 video and AAC audio. Is there a reason why you don't want this? The error you're getting is really one from AV Foundation, and I haven't spent much time with the movie writing functionality there.

Comment: The reason is that the generated video is destinated to different smartphone kind(Android, Blackberry...). Unfortunately many smartphone doesn't support quicktime format and I'm not sure changing the extension only from .mov to .mp4 will work as it were real mpeg4 file.

Comment: @BradLarson I had a same problem, does it have any solution?