# Does GPUImageMovieWriter support AVFileTypeMPEG4 with audio?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, gpuimage

GPUImage has allowed me to manipulate my video files incredibly efficiently in just the way I desire, but only if I use `AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie` when I specify the `fileType` of the `GPUImageMovieWriter`.

My application needs to interact with Android devices which are incapable of playing quicktime movie files, so I attempted to change my code to encode as follows:

```
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) 
              fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 outputSettings:videoCompressionSettings];
```

I am passing the audio through as Brad shows in his example for the movie writer, but my app crashes at the following line relating to audio in the GPUImageMovieWriter.m file within the `setHasAudioTrack` function:

```
[assetWriter addInput:assetWriterAudioInput];
```

I find that if I remove audio completely GPUImage can output an MPEG4 file that plays well with Android. I tried not passing the audio through but subsequently faced crashing in the `[assetWriterAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:audioBuffer];` line of the `processAudioBuffer` method.

I don't want to mess around too much with Brad's code because it has worked so well for me thus far, so I turn to the community to see if anyone has had similar issues and can offer suggestions. I am happy to provide more code, but I am not sure what is relevant and what is not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find it odd that the QuickTime movie default doesn't play on non-iOS (or Mac) devices. The container used should be pretty much the same as used for standard MPEG4 videos, to the point where I've renamed videos like this as ".mp4" and had them play just fine on other devices that supported MPEG4. Someone else had asked the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490798/gpuimagemoviewriter-and-avfiletypempeg4-filetype and I had the same question about this there.

Comment: I spent a good deal of time looking into it, and I eventually just created an `AVAssetExportSession` with and outputFileType of `AVFileTypeMPEG4`. I definitely see what you are saying, but I think the videos might record with a QuickTime file type that is really meant to be a .mov file... and maybe something about .mov files just doesn't play nice? What is more confusing is that i can change the extension to .mp4 on a mac and they play fine... but emailing that to an android doesn't work either.